# Пронумеровать создающиеся поля js

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.
Есть функция для таблицы

```
function addField (argument) {
            var myTable = document.getElementById("mineTable");
            var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
            var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

            var valinRuss = document.createElement("textarea");
            valinRuss.setAttribute("name", "valinRuss" + currentIndex);

            var valinEng = document.createElement("textarea");
            valinEng.setAttribute("name", "valinEng" + currentIndex);

            var valinKaz = document.createElement("textarea");
            valinKaz.setAttribute("name", "valinKaz" + currentIndex);

            var td1 = document.createElement("td1");
            td1.setAttribute("name", "td1" + currentIndex);

            var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(td1);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(valinRuss);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(valinEng);

            currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(valinKaz);

        }
```

И таблица в html типа:

```
<table id="mineTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="+" onclick="addField();">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Знач 1</td>
        <td>Знач 2</td>
        <td>Знач 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td name="td1">1</td>
            <td><textarea name="valinRuss">123</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="valinEng"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="valinKaz"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</table>
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы название первого поля было пронумеровано? Например:
1  (дальше 3 поля input)
2  (дальше 3 поля input)
3  (дальше 3 поля input)
4 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаёте за пределами функции некую переменную-счётчик, в неё записываете цифру 2 (номер второго ряда инпутов), при клике выводите это значение в первую ячейку (`<td name="td1">`) и увеличиваете значение на 1:

```js
var count = 2;
function addField (argument) {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("mineTable");
  var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
  var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

  var valinRuss = document.createElement("textarea");
  valinRuss.setAttribute("name", "valinRuss" + currentIndex);

  var valinEng = document.createElement("textarea");
  valinEng.setAttribute("name", "valinEng" + currentIndex);

  var valinKaz = document.createElement("textarea");
  valinKaz.setAttribute("name", "valinKaz" + currentIndex);

  var td1 = document.createElement("td1");
  td1.setAttribute("name", "td1" + currentIndex);
  td1.innerHTML = count;

  var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(td1);

  currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(valinRuss);

  currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(valinEng);

  currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(valinKaz);
  
  count++;
}

document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].onclick = function(){
  addField();
}
```

```html
<table id="mineTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="+">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Знач 1</td>
        <td>Знач 2</td>
        <td>Знач 3</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <td name="td1">1</td>
            <td><textarea name="valinRuss">123</textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="valinEng"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea name="valinKaz"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```